# Yum install won't work on a boot2docker host?

Tags: docker, boot2docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I'm relatively new to Docker.
I have launch a boot2docker host using docker-machine create -d.

Managed to connect to it, and run few commands. All good.

However, when trying to create a basic http server image, based on centos..
"yum install" simply fails. No matter what is the package.

This is my Docker file:

```
FROM centos
MAINTAINER Amir

#Install Apache
RUN yum install httpd
```

When running:
    docker build .

It's starting to build the image, and everything looks good.. but then fails with:

> Your transaction was saved, rerun it with:
>    yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx.2015-09-18.15-10.q5ss8m.yumtx
>   SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
>   The command '/bin/sh -c yum install httpd' returned a non-zero code: 1

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look bit earlier than the last message, you have a good chance to see something like this:

```
Total download size: 24 M
Installed size: 32 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: Exiting on user command
Your transaction was saved, rerun it with:
```

which means you have to change the default choice, e.g.

```
#Install Apache
RUN yum install -y httpd
```